# Trying to find conformal map

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find a one to one map from $ \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z-1| < 1 \}$ to the right half plane $Re(z)>0$

My approach:  I'm trying to come up with a map that takes $|z-1|<1$ to $0$. Will $z \to \frac{z-z_0}{1-\bar z_0z}$ help me do this? I don't know how to apply it with $|z-1|<1$. I'll call that $f_1(z)$ Then I can use a map between a disk to the right half plane is given by $$z \to - \left (\frac{z+1}{z-1} \right )$$. Call this $f_2(z)$ so that the mapping from $|z-1|<1$ to the right half plane is:

$$f(z)=f_2(f_1(z))$$

Comment: Why don't you just use the translation $f_1(z) = z-1$?

Comment: I didn't know I could do that. I did think about $\frac{z-1}{1-z}$ but then z cannot equal 1.

Comment: But $\frac{z-1}{1-z} \equiv -1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do this in stages. To start with, let's send $|z-1|<1$ to the unit disc: $z \mapsto z-1$. Now that we have the unit disc, we want to get to the right half-plane. Well, we know a formula to get from the unit disc to the *upper* half-plane: $$z \mapsto i\frac{1+z}{1-z}$$

So composing our two maps so far, we get from $|z-1|<1$ to the upper-half plane by $z \mapsto i\frac{z}{2-z}$. Lastly, we want to get from the upper half-plane to the right-half plane; but we can do this by multiplying by $-i$. Putting everything together, we have that $$f(z)=\frac{z}{2-z}$$ is a conformal map from $\{z : |z-1|<1\}$ to the right-half plane.